# Are Javascript typed arrays initialized to 0?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I need a typed array, specifically a Float32Array, of all zeros. I was thinking that I would have to clear it manually, but I noticed that when I declared it, it was already zeroed out. Is this something that is specified in the spec? Can I rely on this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by 'zeroed out'?

Comment: can you show your code? javascript does not have typed arrays. An array contains whatever you decide to put into it; e.g. `[1,"hello",{a:3}]` is a valid array in javascript.

Comment: This is what I get in the console for Google Chrome. `a = new Float32Array(10)` returns `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.
I'm using typed arrays because I am working in WebGL. They're different from the standard array, and since it's primarily for WebGL, it's a little esoteric. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [JavaScript's Typed Array Specification, contents are initialized to 0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#5). So you should be able to rely on this behavior.

Be aware that typed arrays [don't have very good cross browser support yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays). Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera support it, but Internet Explorer only introduced support in IE10.

I should also mention that typed arrays are currently [extremely slow in Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70687) compared to normal arrays. For this reason, you're probably better off avoiding typed arrays unless you aren't targeting Safari. Using normal arrays, all array values are initialized as `undefined`.

Answer (score -5):

By default arrays contain `null` if you construct them with a size. Since `null == 0` you could potentially consider it filled with `0`, or any other falsy value. However you will run into problems if you try to call methods on the numbers, such as `.toString`. Or if you run it through a function that expects a numeric form such as `parseInt`.

Ideally, you should always initialise an array so that you know exactly what it contains, although personally I've never heard of typed arrays in JS...

Comment: *By default arrays contain null if you construct them with a size*: nope. Try in your console: `var a = []; a.length = 5; console.log(a[3])` or `var a = new Array(5); console.log(a[3])`

Comment: Both of those give me an array full of `null`s, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Maybe there's a browser difference? In the Chrome console `console.log(a)` shows `[undefined × 5]`

Comment: Ah, you're right. I was using `JSON.stringify` to try and find out what the "nothings" were, but then `typeof` revealed "undefined". Either way, it's still a falsy value so the point of my answer still stands.

Comment: If you've never heard of typed arrays, why did you answer this question?